# converting varchar(7) to decimal (7,5) in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a values like in hive table

```
0050000
0100000
0005000
```

I would like to convert this to decimal(7,5)
I tried

```
SELECT CAST(column_A AS DECIMAL(7,5)) AS converted_column
FROM table_name;
```

But showing result as NULL
can anyone please suggest the solution for this.

expecting
result should be
0.05000

Comment: Where would the decimal point come from? Try casting to a float, then dividing by one million instead

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, the TRIM() function should work for trimming leading and trailing spaces. However, if you're encountering issues with the TRIM() function, you can alternatively use REGEXP_REPLACE() to remove any leading or trailing spaces.

Here's how you can modify the query using REGEXP_REPLACE():

```
SELECT 
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(column_A, '^\\s+|\\s+$', '') AS DECIMAL(7,5)) 
AS converted_column
FROM table_name;
```

This SQL query will trim leading zeros from the values in column_A and then convert them to decimal(7,5). This should give you the desired result without NULL values.

Comment: inhive Ltrim is not working

Comment: @Prashanth, I modified the answer. Please try the 'Trim' function or REGEXP_REPLACE.